# How format date by country in R?

Tags: r, date, format

I need a simple way to format dates by different country formats. In the ideal case make one setup and use it everywhere in the code.

Let's say for EN and FR formats it should be: YYYY-MM-DD (England) and DD-MM-YYYY (France)

```
# This requires extra work. Each time ask wrapper
format_date <- function(date_obs, country_code) {
  if(country_code == "en") result <- format(date_obs, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  if(country_code == "fr") result <- format(date_obs, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
  result
}

format_date(today(), "en")
format_date(today(), "fr")

# I need this kind of solution
Sys.setlocale(date_format = '%d-%m-%Y')
print(today()) # <<- should be in French format
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `Sys.getlocale()` to see what the local locale is set to and vary `format=` based on that? You can add that logic to your `format_date` or `today` functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are AFAIK no explicity ways to get the preferred date format of a country in R. The only thing you can do is to retrieve it yourself.

Using data from [here](https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156), you can convert the date format in R `strptime` format, and then use it format your dates:

```r
read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlconnor/1887156/raw/014a026f00d0a0a1f5646a91780d26a90781a169/country_date_formats.csv")
date_format <-
  date_format %>% 
  mutate(Date.Format = str_replace_all(Date.Format, c("yyyy" = "%Y", 
                                    "MM" = "%m",
                                    "(?<!M|%)M(?!M)" = "%-m",
                                    "dd" = "%d",
                                    "(?<!d|%)d(?!d)" = "%a"))) %>% 
  select(country = ISO639.2.Country.Code, date_format = Date.Format)


format_to_locale <- function(date, locale) format(date, date_format[date_format$country == locale, "date_format"])
format_to_locale(today(), "FR")
#[1] "07/02/2023"
format_to_locale(today(), "US")
#[1] "02/ 7/2023"
```

This has probably some limitations, but this is a starting point.

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question.