# Is it possible to format Date in R Shiny "datatables" code?

Tags: r, date, dt

I would like to change the Date format when rendering the table in DT::datatable depending on the selected language. Let's say for "EN" the format should be "yyyy-mm-dd", and for FR "dd-mm-yyyy".

Here is a sketch of the code snippet

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)

language <- "en"

df <- data.table(
  date = c("2023-11-09", "2023-11-10", "2023-11-11"),
  value = c(1, 2, 3))

# The format of "date" column should fit selected language
datatable(df) %>% formatDate(language)
```

Any ideas on how to do it in the same manner as "formatPercentage" or "formatCurrency" are welcome and will be appreciated.

Comment: Do we receive the selected language from `Sys.getlocale()`, or is it user input? In the latter case the harder task is to reformat whatever the user inserts to a usuable format I think.

Comment: The language is defined from known user's settings. No need to use getlocale. The question is to have something like "formatPercentage" - "formatDate" with a parameter "language"

Comment: Please elaborate on the language identifier. E.g. if it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 (alpha-2, or alpha-3) this can be done with help of this table: https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156  "2023-11-09" this is the default/how the data is initially stored?

Comment: I tried to give you a starting point. See my improved answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write your own function based on a look-up table and country identifiers of your choice.

For country codes [as those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) (alpha-2, or alpha-3), this [table](https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156) comes in handy. The idea to use this table as well as most of the date reformatting technique is borrowed from @Maël's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374977/how-format-date-by-country-in-r).

As a starting point, I wrapped the ideas in a function called `formatDate2()`. Probably, there are ways to use the power of `DT::formatDate()`. I have not found them yet.

```
# v0.0.2
formatDate2 <- \(dt, language, warn = FALSE) {
  if(warn) 
    warning("Function is written for 'datatables'.\nRequires data column 'date' of class 'character', or 'Date'.")
  if(!any(attributes(dt)$class %in% c("datatables"))) 
    stop("Error: data object is no 'datatables'.")
  if(!("date" %in% names(dt$x$data))) 
    stop("Error: data column `date` is missing.")
  stopifnot(nchar(language) %in% c(2L, 3L))
  if(is.character(dt$x$data$date)) 
    dt$x$data$date <- as.Date(dt$x$data$date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
  ### --- borrowed from Mael --- ###
  lookup <- read.csv(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlconnor/1887156/raw/014a026f00d0a0a1f5646a91780d26a90781a169/country_date_formats.csv")
  lookup$Date.Format <- 
    stringr::str_replace_all(string = lookup$Date.Format, 
                             pattern = c("yyyy" = "%Y", "MM" = "%m",
                                         "(?<!M|%)M(?!M)" = "%m", "dd" = "%d",
                                         "M" = "%M", "2555" = "%Y",
                                         "(?<!d|%)d(?!d)" = "%a"))
  ### ---   ################ --- ###
  if(nchar(language) == 2L) {
    if(!(language %in% lookup$ISO639.2.Country.Code)) 
      stop("Unknown country code.")
    f <- lookup[lookup$ISO639.2.Country.Code == language, "Date.Format"]
  } else {
    if(!(language %in% lookup$ISO.3166.Country.Code)) 
      stop("Unknown country code.")
    f <- lookup[lookup$ISO.3166.Country.Code == language, "Date.Format"]
  }
  dt$x$data$date <- format(x = dt$x$data$date, format = f)
  dt
}
```

You will certainly have to carry out a few more checks and some modifications. As already mentioned by @Maël, the date format shaping w.r.t. `lookup$Date.Format` should also be improved.

```
# your toy data 
library(DT)
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(
  date = c("2023-11-09", "2023-11-10", "2023-11-11"),
  value = c(1:3))
# testing 
df |> DT::datatable() |> formatDate2(language = "US") 
df |> DT::datatable() |> formatDate2(language = "DEU") 
df |> DT::datatable() |> formatDate2(language = "FR") 
df |> DT::datatable() |> formatDate2(language = "ABC")
```

The result for `language = "DEU"` (Germany):

[image]

Comment: I +1 but it's too complicated